Implicit differentiation with 3 codependent variables
I have been going over some exercises on multivariable calculus and have stumbled across the following:
Suppose we have some implicit multivariable function of x,y,z: $$F(x,y,z)=0$$ such that $$x=h(y,z), y=g(x,z), z=f(x,y).$$
show that $$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}  \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = -1$$
Whenever I see the solutions presented to this, they immediately just cite the theorem for implicit differentiation in 3 variables, even though this theorem seems to hinge on the fact that we can, for example, when considering $\frac{dF}{dx}$, let $\frac{dy}{dx}$ be equal to zero since $y$ is not a function of $x$, when clearly it is in this specific case. I am slightly confused by this - is this a consequence of us reducing our problem to one where we need only consider $x,z$ since $y$ wholly depends on them, meaning that we need only consider these two variables instead of all three, bringing us back to one with just 2 independent variables?

There are a number of questions about this identity, see this Approach0 search. I have not combed through the results to see if any of them seem like they would be a duplicate candidate for your question, but maybe they can at least help you refine your question.
